# Prevent Default Click button inside anchor

Tags: jquery, button, onclick, preventdefault

I am using FancyBox --> [jQuery Plugin](http://fancybox.net/howto) to display an image gallery.

[image]

Here's a JSFIDDLE that I'm trying to play around with: --> http://jsfiddle.net/CWaHL/238/

I want the user to be able to delete an image so I created a button on top of the thumbnail image. The button will appear and opacity changes on "mouseover":

[image]

I can click the trash-can button and fire an event (alert). The problem is that FancyBox also fires immediately after the first event (because the button is inside its parent anchor).

If I want this to work properly, I need to only have the trash-can button fire an event and then prevent any event from FancyBox.

Here's my HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="[path to main image]"> 
   <button class="btn btn-danger btn-icon delete_image_btn">
        <i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i>
   </button>
   <img src="[path to thumbnail]" alt="" class='tip' data-placement='top' title='oldman, robot, dance'>
</a>
```

Some jQuery:

```
$('.fancybox-thumbs').on('mouseover',function() {
   $(this).children('img').css('opacity', '0.2');
   $(this).children('button').css('display','block').css('opacity','1');
});

$('.fancybox-thumbs').on('mouseout',function() {
   $(this).children('img').css('opacity', '1');
   $(this).children('button').css('display','none');
});


// My failed attempt to prevent default click
$('.delete_image_btn').click(function() {
   alert('sup');
   $(this).parent('.fancybox-thumbs').prop('onclick', null);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

`e.stopPropagation();` - It will stop propagation of events but it will not stop occurence of fired event. so as per question `e.preventDefault();` will help because it will stop the default action of fired event.

```
$('.delete_image_btn').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thats actually opposite of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to make it so that only ".delete_image_btn" will fire an event. What you have prevents ".delete_image_btn" from firing. But thank you this gives me an idea

Answer (score 4):

You need to stop the further propagation of the event down to the link element. What happens right now is that two different event handlers get fired, because when you click on that button, it is also an implicit click on the surrounding anchor. You now need to prevent that event bubbles up the DOM.

You can use `event.stopPropagation()` to do so:

```
$( '.delete_image_btn' ).click( function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    /* whatever comes next */
} );
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation

Comment: I think I need to revise my post. My question is that I only want ".delete_image_btn" to fire an event. The problem is that when I click the trash-can, the "delete_image_btn" fires the event but then is immediately followed by FancyBox firing. I want to prevent FancyBox from firing.

Comment: @bagofmilk Yes I understood it like that and `stopPropagation` should work in that case. I've updated my description a bit…

Comment: When I use this code only FancyBox fires an event. I'm sorry I'm still confused.

Comment: @bagofmilk We can't help you any further without playing around with the code; a JSfiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Nevermind. I'm wrong. FancyBox was prevented but now it goes directly to the href link.

Comment: I added a jsFiddle. I'm trying to prevent the BIG picture from firing. (it will fire after the two alerts).

Comment: @bagofmilk Mmmh, I don't understand why, but `preventDefault` actually works: http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/CWaHL/242/

Comment: Whats weird is that it works in the jsFiddle and when I copy/paste the code to my project - only fancybox fires ... it doesn't even see the alert. I'll have to sort this out. But thank you

Answer (score 0):

For Preventing any default event just user

```
e.preventDefault();
```

where, `e` stand for event.